# How do i read data to a fragment in kotlin? sharedpreferance

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, sharedpreferences

So i'm going to take some data i'm writing to file in an activity, and i want it to show up in my fragment inside my first activity. I'm quite new to Kotlin and just learned that i can't use the same syntax in framents.

I want to use sharedpreferance.

My Main Activity looks like this, and works fine:

```
private lateinit var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)

        btnSaveEvent.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)

            // Create a shared preference instance
            sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("com.example.gifttracker", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)


            // create editor and add the key value pair to the preference
            val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
            editor.putString("KEY_STR", editText2.text.toString())
            editor.apply()

            //Read from file into a Toast to check that it saved
            val str = sharedPreferences.getString("KEY_STR", null)
            Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        }

    }
```

My fragment is not that great, and looks like this:

```
private var sharedPreferences = this.activity!!.getSharedPreferences("com.example.gifttracker", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frag1, container, false)

        view.btnAddEvent.setOnClickListener {
            requireActivity().startActivity(
                Intent(requireActivity(), Main2Activity::class.java)
            )
        }

        val str = sharedPreferences.getString("KEY_STR", null)
        textView2.text = str

        return view
    }
```

** **Note, this crashes my app** **
This is due to textView2 is null, and i don't know why

I just want to read from the file i created and make a list of it

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
val txt2 = view.findViewById(R.id.textView2)
txt2.text = str
```

instead of 
`textView2.text = str`
Also textView2 should be inside your R.layout.fragment_frag1

Comment: findViewById doesn't work in a fragment, but i solved the issue of textView being null. Just added textView2?. Now the issue is that i can't seem to assert the information into the textView2. No errors though